# .htaccess - How do you do this? http://www.example.com/domain.com

Tags: .htaccess

i want to use somthing like http://www.example.com/domain.com instead of http://www.example.com/index.php?url=domain.com.

how can I do this using .htaccess?

update: i finally figured it out. :)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1
```

http://www.pagerankcheckertool.com/facebook.com

Comment: check this out [http://www.desiquintans.com/cleanurls](http://www.desiquintans.com/cleanurls)

Answer (score 3):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1
```

Comment: Then you've likely goofed something up in `index.php`.

Comment: I mean that the code I gave you is quite simple and commonly used. Something's either wrong with your `index.php`, or your server isn't configured to allow `.htaccess` files or rewrite rules or something like that. Without more information, we can't help you much.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs, it may not be such a good idea to have everything rewritten as per your example, e.g. even a www.example.com/index.html would be rewritten to www.example.com/index.php?url=index.html so i'd recommend you use an initial sub folder or something in the url to seperate your rewritten urls from anything else.. i.e. www.example.com/urls/domain.com

To accomplish that you could setup a rewrite rule.. (assuming you have mod_rewrite active)

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^urls/(.+) /index.php?url=$1 [NC]
```

that basically means any url that begins with urls/ and has one or more characters following.. the brackets around the .+ will 'group' that element and allow you use it again with the $1

Hope that solves what you want to accomplish!

Comment: my current url is like: http://www.example.com/index.php?url=domain.com

i just want it to be like: http://www.example.com/domain.com

Comment: then removing the 'urls/' bit from above should work just make sure you've got the other bits

Comment: It is possible to have a `RewriteRule` execute only if the requested URL is a 404 pre-rewrite, which would address this issue without changing the URL format.

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1

still not working?

Comment: Not sure about the 404 I'm afraid.  Still not having looking with the rewrite then?

Comment: Are you certain mod_rewrite is enabled?  and you have Options +FollowSymLinks ?

Comment: Then as Ceejayoz says, maybe it is redirecting but something is happening in index.php.    Do you have apache log entries you can share with us when you make a request?

Comment: What was it?  for my curiositys sake ;-)

Comment: it's in my original post question. :)