# .htaccess http://domain.tld/index.php?name=domain.com to http://domain.tld/domain.com

Tags: .htaccess

How can i have .htaccess make example from title ?  Visitor will type in his browser http://mydomain.tld/somedomain.tld and my whois script should process http://mydomain.tld/index.php?name=somedomain.tld and return whois result.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess - How do you do this? http://www.example.com/domain.com](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979177/htaccess-how-do-you-do-this-http-www-example-com-domain-com)

Answer (score 0):

Use Apache's `mod_rewrite`.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.tld/index.php?name=$1 [NC]
```

(Not tested, so read up on `mod_rewrite` if this doesn't work precisely as you'd like it to.)

Comment: This might cause infinite redirections.

Comment: Quite true; the regex should be modified to exclude calls to `index.php`. (This is what happens when I go on StackOverflow with half a brain!)

Answer (score 0):

Try following rule in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^name= [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ /index1.php?name=$1 [L,R=301,NE,QSA]
```

RewriteCond above will prevent infinite redirections.

`NC` No Case comparison

`R=301` will redirect with https status 301
`L` will make last rule
`NE` is for no escaping query string
`QSA` will append your existing query parameters

`$1` is your REQUEST_URI